# Excel: Auto overwrite cell A based on cell B input

Tags: excel, vba, exception, excel-formula

Looking for a way to manage the following situation:

[image]

When Input1 =R then I am looking for it to overwrite whatever is in Output with valueX, however when Input1 does not =R then I want to be able to type in the cell with a free selection.

Might be possible through some clever data validation? I know it can be done through vba, however want to try avoid this if possible as will be sending on to other parties who may need to make edits and aren't confident with vba.

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: It cannot be done without vba.

Comment: The only non-VBA solution I can think of involves data validation tables which include all possible answers held in an array ("srcarray"), where the data validation table swaps between allowing "R" or srcarray depending on input 1 value.  Something in the data validatino table list like "=if(a1="R","R",srcarray)".  In that scenario, they would still have to pick the R from the data validation table, but would limit their options

Comment: The image is showing the opposite of what you have written. Which is the one you need?

Answer (score 0):

Well *I* couldn't think of a Non-VBA solution, so maybe the community will think of something, could definitely be possible.

Thankfully, the VBA solution isn't a lot of code, so maybe that will help.

Add this to the code behind of the Worksheet where this data is located (**don't** add to a standard module). I've assumed this data are in column A and B. If that isn't true, simply change the `Target.Column = 1` to the column where Input1 is. Also, I assumed you'd be starting the replacements on Row 2, to not replace the headers.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 And LCase$(Target.Value) = "r" Then Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "X"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## OverWrite Cell feat. the Case Issue

Change the vales in the constants section to fit your needs.
Paste the following code in a sheet code window (in VBA double click on e.g. "Sheet1").

### The Code

```
Option Explicit
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Writes a string to a column in the same row where another
'             string was entered in (copied to) another column.
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const cStrRange As String = "A:A"   ' If Column Range Address
    Const cStrSource As String = "R"    ' If String (Upper Case)
    Const cStrTarget As String = "X"    ' Then String
    Const cIntOffset As Integer = 1     ' Then Column Offset (1 for Next Column)

    ' Each Cell Range i.e. each cell of the range at the intersection
    ' of the If Column Range and the Target's range.
    Dim objCell As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(cStrRange)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each objCell In Intersect(Target, Range(cStrRange))
            If UCase$(objCell) = cStrSource Then
                objCell.Offset(0, cIntOffset) = cStrTarget
            End If
        Next
    End If

ProcedureExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```